# LocationManager Not Providing the Exact Location For First time in samsung devices

Tags: android, location, android-gps

I am Getting user's Current location,When I Clicked for the first time it Showing different location(i.e more than 10kms Away from my current location)
And If I again clicked the Button it showing the exact current location

Note: the issue occurs in **Samsung M series and A series - Android Version 10**

Answer (score 1):

In mycase I solved the problem like this,

Before I used like this

```
location_gps_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View vw) {
            if (location != null) {
                
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
             
                LatLng cur_Latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(cur_Latlng));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));

         
          }
    });
```

Instead of this I updated like this ,It Worked for me

```
location_gps_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View vw) {
                if (location != null) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    
                    LatLng cur_Latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    CameraUpdate currentLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cur_Latlng, 17);
                    googleMap.animateCamera(currentLocation);

            }
        });
```